# How to call .sh script from a JavaFX button`s action handler?

Tags: bash, javafx

```
 btnzero.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

  String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "/home/mat29    /NetBeansProjects/TuberculosisGenomics/test.sh"}; 
  Process procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript)

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported  yet."); 
        }

    });
```

Code returns:

```
xecuting /home/mat29/NetBeansProjects/TuberculosisGenomics/dist/run1712365296/TuberculosisGenomics.jar using platform /home/mat29/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at tuberculosisgenomics.TuberculosisGenomics$3.handle(TuberculosisGenomics.java:107)
    at tuberculosisgenomics.TuberculosisGenomics$3.handle(TuberculosisGenomics.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6866)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Tried also the other function and no result:String path = "/home/mat29/NetBeansProjects/TuberculosisGenomics/test.sh" + "";
                Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try {
                    Process pr = rn.exec(path);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TuberculosisGenomics.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

Comment: No, there was no JavaFX

Comment: Why does that matter? Do you think using the JavaFX API in a java program will somehow break every other java API??? Sure - you have to invoke the correct code when the event handler is executed, but this shouldn't be a problem (???).